# How can I create OR operator in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I need to check if the input element has one of 3 values as I am automating AI feautre and it sometimes generates random text, but still uses at least one value.

So I need to check if input has A or B or C value, one of this values

How can I do this?

Tried this from one of questions here -

```
cy.get('section div:nth-child(4)').invoke('text').then((text) => {
 expect(text).not.equal(companyNameText);
 expect(text).not.equal(descriptionText);
 expect(text).not.equal(purposeText);
})
```

Does not work in my case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress Testing - expect text to be one of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689531/cypress-testing-expect-text-to-be-one-of)

Answer (score 4):

You are testing using `expect(...).not.equal(...)` on all three strings, which results in the opposite test.

Instead you can use string comparison and OR operator,

```js
cy.get('section div:nth-child(4)').invoke('text').then((text) => {
  const matches = (text === companyNameText) ||
    (text === descriptionText) ||
    (text === purposeText);
  expect(matches).to.eq(true)
})
```

---

Another way is [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
cy.get('section div:nth-child(4)').invoke('text').then((text) => {
  const validStrings = [companyNameText, descriptionText, purposeText]
  const matches = validStrings.includes(text)
  expect(matches).to.eq(true)
})
```

or a variation with `.to.include()` matcher

```js
cy.get('section div:nth-child(4)').invoke('text').then((text) => {
  const validStrings = [companyNameText, descriptionText, purposeText]
  expect(validStrings ).to.include(text)
})
```

---

Even more, it's possible to use `cy.contains()` with a RegExp that has OR operator built in

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`${companyNameText}|${descriptionText}|${purposeText}`);
cy.contains('section div:nth-child(4)', regex)
```

---

Another one, with `.should()`

```js
cy.get('section div:nth-child(4)')
  .should('have.any.text', (companyNameText, descriptionText, purposeText))
```

Answer (score 1):

[You an use Chai's `oneOf` method to achieve this.](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) There is a caveat from the docs:

> Asserts that the target is a member of the given array list. However, it’s often best to assert that the target is equal to its expected value.

```js
cy.get('section div:nth-child(4)').invoke('text').then((text) => {
  expect(text).to.be.oneOf(
    [companyNameText, descriptionText, purposeText]
  );
});
```